# How to fix Error loading 'wk' package in R?

Tags: r, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am getting the following error message when trying to load 'wk' package in R:

```
> install.packages("wk")
Retrieving 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/wk_0.8.0.tar.gz' ...
    OK [file is up to date]
Installing wk [0.8.0] ...
    FAILED
Error installing package 'wk':
==============================

* installing *source* package ‘wk’ ...
** package ‘wk’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -I"/opt/R/4.1.3/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c bbox-handler.c -o bbox-handler.o
bbox-handler.c: In function ‘wk_bbox_handler_realloc_result’:
bbox-handler.c:44:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
     ^
bbox-handler.c:44:5: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
bbox-handler.c: In function ‘wk_bbox_handler_append’:
bbox-handler.c:65:9: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
         for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         ^
bbox-handler.c: In function ‘wk_c_bbox_handler_new’:
bbox-handler.c:173:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     ^
bbox-handler.c: In function ‘wk_envelope_handler_vector_start’:
bbox-handler.c:201:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     ^
bbox-handler.c: In function ‘wk_c_envelope_handler_new’:
bbox-handler.c:308:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     ^
make: *** [bbox-handler.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘wk’
* removing ‘/home/mmagona/renv/staging/2/wk’
Error: install of package 'wk' failed [error code 1]
```

Can't find much information regarding this error and I need it's stopping me from installing 'sf' package also. Any help appreciated.

I am using R version 4.1.3

Comment: Are you running `library(wk)` or `install.packages("wk")`. Is that really the full output you see? Normally there is a more detailed error message earlier in the output. Since you are running an older version of R, you will need to setup your computer to compile package since usually precompiled packages are only available for current versions of R. Are you on a Mac, Windows, or Linux machine?

Comment: @MrFlick I have updated the full error message. I am using Windows. So you're saying it's a case of just updating my R version?

Comment: From paths (i.e. `/opt/R/4.1.3/` & `/home/mmagona/renv/staging/2/wk`) it doesn't look like Windows.  RStudio Server / Posit Workbench ?

Comment: @margusl sorry yeah it's linux